# Consuming Spring Cloud Config Server configuration through a NestJS application with encrypted data

Tags: node.js, encryption, nestjs, spring-cloud-config-client

Currently I'm working trying to read the Spring Cloud Config Server configurations through a NestJS app. I found some packages like `cloud-config-client` and `node-scc-config` but I need to decrypt some keys that are encrypted using JCE. The endpoint is also a secured with Basic Authorization header, but with those packages is not possible to connect and get the configuration. Is possible to get them in some way and decrypt encrypted `{cipher}XXX` config keys?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access Spring Config Server from non-spring application.
in your case, i think the best approach is to use there REST API.

#### API Resources `non-spring applications`

`application` is injected as the `spring.config.name` in the SpringApplication (what is normally application in a regular Spring Boot app).
`profile` is an active profile (or comma-separated list of properties).

| Path | Method | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| /`application`/`profile` | GET | Configuration data for app for Spring profile (comma-separated). |
| /`application`/`profile`/`label` | GET | an optional git label (defaults to `master`). |

more details can be found in there doc [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config)